# How I can understand the following sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, word-in-context

> He has a certain way about him.

Can i understand in this way–He hold certain manner /behavior which is connected to him– or anything else?

Comment: We _have_ a manner, we don't _hold_ one. _About him_ just emphasises the fact that it's _his_ way or manner that is being referred to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very particular idiom. Saying someone has "a certain way" means that there is something notable, possibly *unusual* about that person that is *difficult to define or put into few words*.

Maybe you've heard the French expression (often borrowed by English speakers and found in some English dictionaries) "*je ne sais quoi*"? This is similarly used to refer to an indescribable quality, but a positive, attractive one. By contrast, "a certain way" (or 'a certain manner') can suggest a negative trait.

Comment: This mean"It's hard to describe his personality."

Comment: Way mean- characteristics, so can i say "he has such  characteristics which are hard to defined"?